# How program to see if the function is enabled?

Tags: java, android, camera

I work with `Camera2API` and I have a`set ()`which should activate the work of`FaceDetection`, it looks like this

```
mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE,
                                    CameraMetadata.STATISTICS_FACE_DETECT_MODE_FULL);
```

and after I set it FACE_DETECT_MODE must be active, but it seems to me that he still does not turn on. I want to check whether it is switched on ... Is there a function that returns true or false?